# How to make sure that even if no data is given in the required field, it will consider is empty?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am using Node.js and MongoDB. I want to make sure that if the user writes in the specific field, the database should be updated with that value, else it should be `null`.

Following is the code I am using:

```
exports.updatingUser = async (user_,request,res)=> {

    let result = "";

    const updateUserInfo = {
        fullName: request.fullName,
        userName: request.userName,
        email :request.email,
        password : request.password,
        profileImage:request.profileImage,
        backgroundImage:request.backgroundImage
    };

    await User.updateOne({_id:request._id},{$set:updateUserInfo})
        .exec()
        .then(docs => {
            result = docs;
        })
        .catch(err => {
            res.status(500).json({
                error: err
            });
        });
    return result;
}
```

This works when the user writes in the specific fields but not when any of the field is empty.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
fullName: request.fullName ? request.fullName : '', // You can put null if you want
```

Note: Need to put in all

Comment: Didn't get the logic, Why request.fullName ? request.fullName ?

Comment: @virk It's callled ternary operator. This is called simple if and else condition. So in our case, it says, if we have fullName then use fullName else put "" in object